# How do you determine the type of software.amazon.jsii.JsiiObject in Java AWS CDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How do you determine the underlying AWS CDK type of software.amazon.jsii.JsiiObject in Java AWS CDK?

In AWS CDK each JsiiObject is casted into a AWS CDK Type such as [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html)

For example [getSecurityGroupIngress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/java/software/amazon/awscdk/services/ec2/CfnSecurityGroup.html)() which is a method in AWS CDK returns a JssiObject that is cast into (List) in the following code. However as the documentation suggests that the type returned in Object, I'm not clear what AWS CDK type the JssiObject that is contained in the Object represents.

```
 CfnSecurityGroup cfnSecurityGroup = (CfnSecurityGroup) resource_SecurityGroup.getCfnresource();

 if (cfnSecurityGroup.getSecurityGroupIngress() != null) {

    List<CfnSecurityGroupIngress> cfnSecurityGroupIngress = (List<CfnSecurityGroupIngress>) cfnSecurityGroup.getSecurityGroupIngress();
```

How do you determine the AWS CDK type of the JsiiObject?

Maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awscdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdk-cloudformation-include</artifactId>
        <version>1.79.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Regards
Conteh

Comment: It's a `software.amazon.jsii.JsiiObject`.

Comment: Make call `getClass()` on the instance and print its classname.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I've updated the question to be more clear. I originally wrote it thinking everyone understood AWS CDK but it wasn't clear I agree. I think it is much more clear. Please vote to reopen as I would love to know the answer to this question and I"m sure in future others will as well as AWS CDK gets more use.

Comment: You should clarify whether "the following code" is in the library itself, in official documentation, or in some example you found. Note also that the Amazon SDK 2, while a massive improvement over the train wreck that was SDK 1, is autogenerated and has some really obnoxious rough edges, like using lists of pairs (which require builder chains for construction!) for things that should just be a simple `Map`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thanks,,I've added the clarification that the method getSecurityGroupIngress() is a AWS CDK method in the AWS CDK Java library 1.79

Comment: Note that I know the answer for this if the question is reopened

Answer (score 0):

This will work in some cases such as the above example however some JsiiObject are not easily converted to a JsonNode as they may represent a List for example so although it may help, it may not be the best answer.

```
 public void PrintObjectAsJson(Object obj) throws IOException {

    JsiiObject J = (JsiiObject) obj;
    JsonNode jsonNode = (JsonNode) J.$jsii$toJson();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Object json = mapper.readValue(jsonNode.toString(), Object.class);
    LOG.debug(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json));

  }
```

Given the above example

```
CfnSecurityGroup cfnSecurityGroup = (CfnSecurityGroup) resource_SecurityGroup.getCfnresource();

    if (cfnSecurityGroup.getSecurityGroupIngress() != null) {

      List<Object> cfnSecurityGroupIngress
              = (List<Object>) cfnSecurityGroup.getSecurityGroupIngress();

      ListIterator<Object> it = cfnSecurityGroupIngress.listIterator();

      while (it.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = it.next();
        PrintObjectAsJson(obj);
```

This outputs the following which tells us the object has an interface AWS CDK type of [CfnSecurityGroup.IngressProperty](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.CfnSecurityGroup.IngressProperty.html)

```
{
  "$jsii.byref" : "Object@10016",
  "$jsii.interfaces" : [ "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2.CfnSecurityGroup.IngressProperty" ]
}
```